# Does it make sense to use CSRF protection for anonymous users?

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

Should CSRF protection be used for anonymous users, or does that defeat its purpose?

I have a URL that can be accessed anonymously. When the URL is accessed with the appropriate information, some values are updated in my database.  For example, a client can place some code on their order confirmation page that will make a POST request to `http://example.com/save-request` with the following data sent:

```
{orderId: 1234, referralCode: 'ABCDEF'}
```

When I receive this request, I update the given order in my database with the referral code:

```
$order = Order::find(Input::get('orderId'));
$order->referral_code = Input::get('referralCode');
$order->save();
```

I am trying to protect this URL from abuse so that a user can't send requests for random Order IDs and try to get their referral code associated to them.

CRSF protection comes to mind, but that would mean I need to first fetch the token, which would require another public URL. It seems like that would make it slightly harder for abuse, but still possible since the abuser can simply fetch a token, and then make requests as normal.

Are there any strategies to protect against this sort of abuse?

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for progammers.stackexchange. Can it be transferred over or should I repost it there?

Comment: Is your client already authenticated when at the order confirmation page making the POST request? Or are they anonymous?

Comment: @light They are anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF is meant to protect **authenticated** sessions. The basic idea is: the server provides a CSRF token to the client for all authenticated sessions. The client should pass the same CSRF token to the server with each subsequent request. So if a request came without the token, the server should ignore / log it. Your CSRF token should ideally only be passed to the client **upon authentication**. If there's a separate URL to get the CRSF token, it becomes pointless.

In your case, since the users are always anonymous at "order confirmation", CSRF protection would not be too applicable. I think the best strategy would be to model the data and your API such that each "order confirmation" is one atomic request with an optional "referralCode". Your API function/endpoint, possibly `/confirm-order`, can then take `referralCode` and save it into the `Order` object, along with any other confirmation processing logic. The API function/endpoint to edit order, maybe `/edit-order`, should require authentication. Then, the standard CSRF protection applies.

However, if your intention is to allow **anonymous** users to change their order details including `referralCode`, you can mitigate abuse by tracking changes, and allowing only a maximum number of changes. You may also add in some time restriction if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of CSRF and confirming it's not useful for anonymous users. Unfortunately in this case the orders are being placed with a 3rd party shopping cart. The post request to my URL is not the same URL as the website the order was placed on, so making a single request is not an option. I had the same idea to use a time constraint (ie, referral code can't be added more than 2 minutes after order is placed). I think that's my best option.

Comment: @flyingL123 so the orders are stored on a 3rd party database, while the referralCode data is stored on your site DB? Sounds like a complicated data model that is gonna be susceptible to abuse.

Comment: The orders are placed via a Bigcommerce store. They get the order and store it in their database, then fire a webhook to tell me there was a new order. I then pull in the order data via their API and save it to my database. Then I look to see if there is an order referral request queued up for that order, and if so, update the order with the appropriate referral code in my database.  It's way more complicated than it should be, but that's the way things work with Bigcommerce :)

Comment: Ok I think I understand better now. If their webhook to your server allows some sort of "passthrough" variable and you have control of the order submission form, you may also include an authentication token to it. Then, your `/save-request` call which updates `referralCode` should also include that token as parameter. This is sort of like authenticating that `/save-request` came from the same client as the one who made the order at Bigcommerce.

Comment: That's a really great idea. Unfortunately I'm unable to pass any additional information to the order.

Comment: Hmm... are order IDs generated by BigCommerce or you?

Comment: They are generated by Bigcommerce.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that a CSRF token is not useful for unauthenticated requests but it also makes no harm and adds no extra work (in case of Laravel), so in most cases there are no real reasons to omit it here and there.

What regards to solution of your problem, try replacing an `id` of an order with something like a generated random `order_number` which is much more difficult to guess than a simple id.

Another solution is something like this:

```
$order = Order::where('id', '=', Input::get('orderId'))
    ->where('created_at', '=', Input::get('createdAt'))->first();

if ($order) {
    $order->referral_code = Input::get('referralCode');
    $order->save();
}
```

In this case a user has to guess an `id` and also guess when a particular order has been created.

And you can also mix both solutions (`order_number` and `created_at`).

It's not a perfect 100% solution but drastically decreases probability of fraud.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't quite understand how CSRF tokens help prevent human mistakes w.r.t. CORS. Would you care to clarify? The links you provided do not say anything about that. I think it is more important to understand "How CORS attacks work" - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29. The introduction already illuminates what it is meant to protect against. In the OP's case, CSRF attacks are not the main concern - fraud/abuse prevention is.

Comment: I've never said that CSRF protection is the main concern in the OP's case, so I completely agree here. Secondly, you're right that I have to remove that CORS nonsense from my answer, because it's wrong (I re-read the article where I read this). But my main point is that intentionally omitting protection is even more pointless than implementing it for unauthenticated requests. This token makes no harm and adds no extra work (at least in case of Laravel) but can potentially lead to mistakes (e.g. another programmer decides to add authentication to that page and forgets to add the missing token).

Comment: Agree. It's easy to implement CSRF, and all systems should implement it (properly) whenever possible, i.e. assign a CSRF token upon login, and expect all subsequent requests to include it (possibly in headers) until logout. I don't think we should intentionally omit CSRF, but I do think that implementing correctly matters. e.g. having a URL to fetch CSRF Tokens totally defeats the purpose of CSRF protection - within the attack, the attacker may just use that same URL to fetch the token.